# Opening the same activity more than once

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I am facing two kinds of problems. One is the existing activity is overridden(**when the app is in foreground**). Second is the existing activity is not overridden and not opening another same activity(**when the app is in background**).

1. I have service in the background which triggers an activity(NotificationMessageActivity) when the app is in foreground based on some previously configured rule by the user. My problem is if users set two rules at some seconds difference, if first NotificationMessageActivity is opened, without closing the existing activity if the service triggers another activity the existing activity is overridden. Can someone please let me know how to keep both the activities or any elegant way to handle this situation? Tried with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` but no luck. Below is my code.

   ```
   Intent intent= new Intent(this, NotificationMessageActivity .class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.putExtra("message",messageBody);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Below is my code opening an activity on tap of notification when app is in background. Here the activity is not opened and not overriding the existing one on tap of another notification.

   ```
   Intent  intent= new Intent(AppScreen.this, NotificationMessageActivity .class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   intent.putExtra("message",notificationMessage);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: Did you try specifying `singleTop` launchMode for the `NotificationMessageActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: @PravinSonawane Tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

first finish the acivity

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, NotificationMessageActivity .class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("message",messageBody);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Sorry I think you didn't get my question. I am trying to open another activity from notification tap without destroying current activity

Comment: just use finish() function

Answer (score 0):

If you app is in foreground then you onNewIntent() method of current activity will be called when you click on notification and call a pending intent. In that method you can do what ever code you want to do.

Here is an example for sending notification

```
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String eventId, boolean isAppInBackground, String notificationType) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_BACKGROUND, isAppInBackground);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

In my HomeActivity I am checking if app is in background and notification is clicked OnCreate of that activity will be called and if app is in foreground and notification is clicked onNewIntent() method of that activity will be called.